# How to remove the empty columns from dataframe of pyspark

Tags: pyspark

[name data](https://github.com/1576dkm/name)

we have a dataframe:

```
names = spark.read.csv("name.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true").rdd
```

I want to do this:

```
res=names.filter(lambda f: f['Name'] == "Diwakar").map(lambda name: (name['Name'], name['Age']))
res.toDF(['Name','Age']).write.csv("final", mode="overwrite", header="true")
```

**but empty column is creating the problem.**

Comment: where is the data?????

Comment: @abhishekhmishra now, i have added the link of the csv file

Comment: why the `lambda` ? oO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a simple select,
I am assuming that empty columns are " ".

for input

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,"", "x"," "), (2,"", "b"," "), (5,"", "c"," "), (8,"", "d"," ")], ("st"," ", "ani"," "))

+---+---+---+---+
| st|   |ani|   |
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|   |  x|   |
|  2|   |  b|   |
|  5|   |  c|   |
|  8|   |  d|   |
+---+---+---+---+

a=list(set(df.columns))
a.remove(" ")
df=df.select(a)
df.show()

+---+---+
|ani| st|
+---+---+
|  x|  1|
|  b|  2|
|  c|  5|
|  d|  8|
+---+---+
""" 
Do your Operations
"""
```

once done with  the above step go on with your task. this will remove blank columns

**New Edit:**

There is no such way to drop empty columns while reading, you have to do it yourself.

You can do it like this:

```
a = list(set(df.columns))
new_col = [x for x in a if not x.startswith("col")] #or what ever they start with

df=df.select(new_col)
```

Comment: Please take a look at data once again, data have empty columns without names.I want to know how to remove empty column.

Comment: that's what the code dose.. i have added an example as well

Comment: It does remove the empty column of self created dataframe.....but if we will create dataframe using read.csv then the default name is given to the empty column name.....can we overcome this error

Comment: Is there a way to take fhe csv file as it is? can we stop spark putting the default name to the column.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test_Parquet").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
names = spark.read.csv("name.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")
names.show()
temp = list(names.columns)
print(temp)
temp.remove(" 1")
temp.remove(" 3")
temp.remove("_c5")
print(temp)
names = names.select(temp)
names.show()
```

if you will create the dataframe while you use read.csv then spark will automatically give the default name to the unnamed column, and you will have to remove the column's explicitly.But it throws the following error:

```
CSV header does not conform to the schema.
 Header: Name,  , Age,  , Class, 
 Schema: Name,  1, Age,  3, Class, _c5
```

and now you can continue with your job.

Comment: Is there a way to take fhe csv file as it is? ....can we stop spark putting the default name to the column. ....

Comment: I am also looking for the same.....but till now i don't have any answer to this question. .....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove data with empty rows in a pyspark data frame is:

`newDF = oldDF.filter("colName != ''")`.

In your case you can filter the initial `names` data frame and the apply your conditions:

```
res=names.filter("Name != ''") # I have applied filter on 'Name' column of your data.
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Please take a look at data once again, data have empty columns without names.I want to know how to remove empty column .